# What is the parallel of this code without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to rewrite this code in pure JavaScript, i.e. without jQuery. It gets the content of a `div` and adds it after the first image in another `div`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var teksti = $('#inside1').html();
    $('<div id="inside1">' + teksti + '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>').insertAfter("#artikull > p > img:first");
    });
```

Comment: What is `imazhi` defined as?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? There is no real complex jQuery stuff, just basic DOM operations.

Comment: sorry, i just made an edit to the code. the imazhi var isnt needed

Comment: I can get the content of the div. but i dont know how to access the first image inside a div.

Comment: look fo innerTHML() and outerHTML() javascript function. And getElementById(). For the first img, look for nodes and childNodes.

Comment: var teksti = document.getElementById('inside1').innerHTML;

Comment: have a look at [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) - it should help you get the image

Comment: this is as far as i am now:

function adddiv(){
 var teksti = document.getElementById('inside1').innerHTML;
 var div = document.getElementById('artikull');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + teksti;
}

Comment: and this isnt working:

function adddiv(){
 var teksti = document.getElementById('inside1').innerHTML;
 var div = document.getElementById('artikull');
        var imazh = div.getElementsByTagName('img');
        imazh.innerHTML = imazh.innerHTML + teksti;
}

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to support modern browsers, it's not too complicated:

```
// $(document).ready(function() {
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // var teksti = $('#inside1').html();
    var teksti = document.getElementById('inside1').innerHTML;

    // $('<div id="inside1">' + teksti + '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>')
    //     .insertAfter("#artikull > p > img:first");
    document
        .querySelector('#artikull > p > img')
        .insertAdjacentHTML(
            'afterend',
            '<div id="inside1">' + teksti + '</div><div style="clear:both">'
        );

// });
});
```

The roughly equivalent lines from the original jQuery are in the comments.

I'm a little confused, though; the code you've presented will create an element with the same ID as the original one and ends up with a couple of `div`s in a `p`—resulting in a somewhat deformed DOM. Wouldn't you prefer to simply wrap the existing element and move it instead of creating a new one with exactly the same content, and shouldn't you move it somewhere that accepts block-level children?

Answer (score 0):

```
function adddiv(){
    var teksti = document.getElementById('inside1').innerHTML;
    var div = document.getElementById('artikull');
        var imazh = div.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        imazh.outerHTML = imazh.outerHTML + teksti;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should be compatible in modern browsers and IE from version 9.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {

    var insideHTML = '<div id="inside1">' + window.document.getElementById('inside1').innerHTML + '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>',
        artikullElement = window.document.getElementById('artikull'),
        pElements = (function (nodes) {

            var results = [],
                node;

            for (var i = 0, iLen = nodes.length; i < iLen; i++) {

                node = nodes[i];

                // Get all children P tags
                if (node.nodeValue === 1 && node.tagName === "P")
                    results.push(node);
            }

            return results;

        })(artikullElement.childNodes),
        imgElement = (function (nodes) {

            var node;

            for (var i = 0, iLen = nodes.length; i < iLen; i++) {

                // Get the first child tag image found in any of the P tags
                if (node.nodeValue === 1 && node.tagName === "IMG")
                    return node;
            }

        })(pElements);

    if (imgElement) {

        if (imgElement.insertAdjacentHTML)
            imgElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', insideHTML);

        else {

            var range = window.document.createRange(),
                docFragment = range.createContextualFragment(insideHTML);

            imgElement.parentNode.insertBefore(docFragment, imgElement.nextSibling);
        }
    }

});
```